# Python Selenium to go a field in webpage and enter new value

Tags: python, html, selenium-chromedriver

I have the below full path from my web page.
/html/body/ui-view/div/ui-view/md-content/div[2]/md-card/div[1]/div/div/md-sidenav/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/date-range-picker/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/md-input-container/input

md-input-container is shown below,

I need to remove the value already in this field on the webpage and enter new value .
I tried different ways to do it ..but failed.

Please any one help me on this.

Comment: <md-input-container id="startTimeInput" class="md-input-has-value"><input type="text" ng-model="vm.startTime" tabindex="1" ng-change="vm.onUpdateRange('left'); vm.pickerUpdate()" class="dateInput ng-pristine ng-valid md-input ng-not-empty _md-autofocus ng-touched" ng-class="{invalid:!vm.isFromValid}" md-autofocus="vm.setFocus()" id="input_8" aria-invalid="false" style=""><div class="md-errors-spacer"></div></md-input-container>

Comment: Please add the code to your question rather than a comment. Also, elaborate on what you have already tried

Comment: for example i tried to do use as shown bleow code  but not working  driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="input_8"]')  driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="input_8"]')

Comment: driver.find_element_by_id('input_8') failed  and driver.find_elements_by_name('input_8')

Comment: driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".glyphicon.glyphicon-tasks").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_id("input_8")            error no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="input_8"]"}

Comment: when i print the webelment in my sourcepage  it was showing in something is hidden...<div class="home-app-icon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span></div>